# Switch statement - "unreachable code detected"

Tags: string, switch-statement

Visual Studio gives me this error message: "Unreachable code detected". Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?:

```
string commandWord = command.CommandWord;   //--> here I get the error message

switch (commandWord) 

(

case "help":

printHelp();

break;



case "go":

goRoom (command);

break; 

case "pick":

pickUp (command);

break; 

)
```

Comment: after switch case it should be { code } .Put your code in curly braces.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo: the brackets are wrong , it should be curly braces- {}

```
switch (commandWord)

{

case "help":

printHelp();

break;

case "go":

goRoom (command);

break;

case "pick":

pickUp (command);

break;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) change
one possiblility:

```
string commandWord = command.CommandWord;
```

to

```
string commandWord = command.CommandWord();
```

or you might need to include guard clause: like so:

```
string commandWord = command.CommandWord;
#pragma warning disable 0162
switch (commandWord)
{
    case "help":
        printHelp();
    break;
    case "go":
        goRoom (command);
    break;
    case "pick":
        pickUp (command);
    break;
}
#pragma warning restore 0162
```

2) change parenthesis to curly brace like so:

```
switch (commandWord)
**{**
    case "help":
        printHelp();
    break;
    case "go":
        goRoom (command);
    break;
    case "pick":
        pickUp (command);
    break;
**}**
```

on MAC, you have curly brace:

- For { use the following combination:

> Alt + (

- For } use the following combination:

> Alt +)

Comment: Yes, I know about the curly brackets. I was not able to find them on my friends mac :) But it still does not work :(

Comment: if you are programming in C#, i recommend you read this: http://www.dotnetperls.com/unreachable